# JbossTextMessage Unicode convert failed in Linux

Tags: unicode, jboss, jms, message-driven-bean, mq

I'm trying to upload a xml (UTF-8) file and post it on a Jboss MQ. When reading the file from the listener UTF-8 characters are not correctly formatted ONLY in the Jboss (jboss-5.1.0.GA-3) instance running on Linux.

For an instance: **BORÅS** is converted to **BOR¿S** at Linux jboss instance.

When I copy and configure the same jboss instance to run at Windows (SP3) it works perfectly.

Also I have change the default setting in Linux by including JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in .bashrc and run.sh files.

inside the Listener JbossTextMessage.getText() is coming with incorrectly specified character.

Any suggestions or workarounds ?

Comment: Please provide exact information regarding how do you upload the file.

Comment: I have exposed a jsp to upload a xml file using the post method. I will be obtaining the file as a FormFile using struts in the Action class as follwos: 

FormFile file = theForm.getFile(); 

Secondly, I retrieve the file data as byte array 

byte[] buf = file.getFileData(); 

Finally, I post this in a queue in Jboss (jboss-5.1.0.GA-3).

Comment: Process is follows:      
(1)Upload the XML ---> (2)Obtain the byte[] from the file ---> (3)put it on a JMS queue ---> (4)picked by a MDB to process. 

When the posted Message is received from the listener I tried to cast it as follows but didn't work  :    

((TextMessage) message).getText().getBytes("UTF-8")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to find a solution, BUT the solution is still a blackbox. If anyone have the answer to WHY it has failed/successful please update the thread.

Solution at a glance :
1. Captured the file contents as a byte arry and wrote it to a xml file in jboss tmp folder using FileOutputStream

2. When posting to the jboss Message queue, I used the explicitly wrote xml file  (1st step) using a FileInputStream as a byte array and pass it as the Message body.

Code example:

**View**: JSP page with a FormFile

**Controller Class** :UploadAction.java

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
   ...........

   writeInitFile(theForm.getFile().getFileData()); // Obtain the uploaded file

   Message msg = messageHelper.createMessage( readInitFile() ); // messageHelper is a customized factory method to create Message objects. Passing the newly    
   wrote file's byte array.

   messageHelper.sendMsg(msg); // posting in the queue

   ...........
}

private void writeInitFile(byte[] fileData) throws Exception{

   File someFile = new File("/jboss-5.1.0.GA-3/test/server/default/tmp/UploadTmp.xml");  // Write the uploaded file into a temporary file in jboss/tmp folder
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);

   fos.write( fileData );

   fos.flush();
   fos.close();     
}

private byte[]  readInitFile() throws Exception{

   StringBuilder buyteArray=new StringBuilder();

   File someFile = new File("/jboss-5.1.0.GA-3/test/server/default/tmp/UploadTmp.xml");  // Read the Newly created file in jboss/tmp folder

   FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(someFile);

   int ch;
   while( (ch = fstream.read()) != -1){
        buyteArray.append((char)ch);
   }
   fstream.close();

   return buyteArray.toString().getBytes();   // return the byte []
}
```

*Foot Note:* I think it is something to do with the Linux/Windows default file saving type. eg: Windows default : ANSI.